# security, efficiency - where to host user database

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, cpanel

I am creating a subscription based website. In order to access certain parts of the site, the user must have a login/password.

Currently, I am using a mysql db on cPanel (on godaddy). In terms of both security and efficiency, would I be better off hosting my db somewhere else such as on a virtual server or AWS? Or, is it fine to just use cPanel to host my user db?

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say where your cPanel is hosted. cPanel is a software platform, and it can run anywhere, on physical servers or virtual servers. It is a common web-based interface for several hosting companies.

The wide-area network of the internet has a lot of latency, compared to local networks. If you send a query from your application to the database in AWS, you could expect it to take a substantial amount of time. https://www.cloudping.co/ shows a summary of latency between AWS regions. For example, the latency from us-east-1 to us-east-2 is 13.77ms. But the latency between us-west-2 to us-east-1 is 101.20ms.

Whereas latency within the same local network is typically measured in microseconds (not milliseconds). So it's 2 to 3 orders of magnitude lower than WAN latency.

For this reason, it's common wisdom that the database should be co-located with the application code that submits the SQL queries. They should be in the same data center, on the same internal network.

It still takes time for the RDBMS to execute the query of course. The network doesn't affect that. But at least you can eliminate the overhead of the network latency.

So if you put your database in AWS, you better put the application in AWS too, in the same region.

Comment: Thanks for the great response... cPanel is through godaddy